# Adding Data Label and Marker to the Line chart using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have tried various approaches adding the marker and label to the line chart.

I tried with enter() method to add circles to the linechart. what I am able to get is the beginning or first point at the group level as mentioned in the snapshot.

Here, is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/0m5sbbcb/7/) which I have tried till now.

Please advice, If there is any further information required.

Following is the snippet which I have tried to create marker

```
g.append('circle')
                    .attr("class"   ,"circle")    
                    .attr('cx',function(d) { return xScale(d[0]) ; })
                    .attr('cy',function(d) { return xScale(d[1]) ; })
                    .attr('r',22);
```

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second @TomShanley answer but you should not be using the enter `.data[[data]]` as you are not using the data itself. You should instead just add `svg` elements using d3. Later on you can add the data as needed to create the circles.

You should also not have `<svg>` elements inside `<g>` or others `<svg>`

Here is the updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/mghays6a/1/

Comment: Thank You !! Can I know why it is not showing x-axis in your fiddle as it was in my fiddle ?

Comment: However, when I inspect the svg element and add the scroll the height  it's showing x-axis also. I think I have to change margin properties

Comment: Yes, mine is not showing the x-axis due to some transform I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The enter selection that you are using for the circles, is based off the append for the line that uses `.data([data])`. While this is OK for lines/paths (as you want one element), this won't work when you want separate elements per datum.

You should do a separate `selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()...etc`, where the data is not in the square brackets. This will give you separate elements for each circle.